# JS Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, infinite

I use this https://infinite-scroll.com

For normal scrolling through pages it works great out of the box.

I have a problem though, I have a regular navigation at the top of my page. What I would like to accomplish is this:

Visitor enters site. page-1 is loaded
Visitor clicks Page-3 in my navigation, I would like page-2 to load and then page-3 and automatically scroll down to page-3

each page starts with a div with and ID e.g.

```
function checkAnchor( anchor ) {

        if ( $( anchor ).length ) {
            return true;
        } else {

            $( '.article-feed' ).infiniteScroll( 'loadNextPage' );
            checkAnchor( anchor );
        }       

    }

$( document ).on( 'click', 'a[href^="#"]', function ( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        anchor = $.attr( this, 'href' );

        while ( checkAnchor( anchor ) == false ) {              

            $( '.article-feed' ).infiniteScroll( 'loadNextPage' );

        }

        $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
            scrollTop: $( $.attr( this, 'href' ) ).offset().top
        }, 700 );

    } );
```

I have tried many different things to accomplish this but I cant seem to get it to work. The next page loads but i have to click to link until page-3 is finally loaded. Any help is welcome

Comment: So you mean you do not want to skip the loading of page-2 when user clicks on page 3 ?

Comment: No i would like page 2 to load and then page 3 as if the user scrolls down to page 3 manually

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i meant

Comment: Can you add a codepen or fiddle / plunkr ?

Comment: `while ( checkAnchor( anchor ) == false )`  I don't use infinate-scroll, but this piece of code is `sync`, the loading of the page is going to be `async`, so you can't do that.  Ideally, Infinate-scroll could do with a pageLoaded callback you could use, but if your pages have specific tags / ids then you could wait using a setInterval callback.

Comment: setInterval worked for me, I do feel like I hacked my way through this though

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkAnchor( anchor ) {

        if ( $( anchor ).length ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            setInterval( function () {

                $( '.article-feed' ).infiniteScroll( 'loadNextPage' );

                var lastAnchor = "#" + $( ".anchor" ).last().attr( 'id' );

                if ( anchor == lastAnchor ) {
                    $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
                        scrollTop: $( anchor ).offset().top
                    }, 500 );
                    return true;
                } 

            }, 100 );
        }
    }
```

This kind of did the trick but I feel like I am hacking my way through this